# Firediff plugin

Tags: html, firebug, joomla1.5

I am relatively new to Web Development, and I am messing with a Joomla template installation.

I managed to get firebug to make changes and Firediff to save them as a new CSS, and replaced the CSS file on the server.

What I would now like to do is edit the template elements, (mostly deleting unused template elements), on screen using firebug, and then save the changes to a new HTML document.

My trouble is that I cannot work out where the correct html is to replace on the server.

Only by using Dreamweaver I can ascertain that the file name is index.html, but there are many files called this on the server.

With the CSS file I was able to identify the server path and filename from the blue text in the right panel of firebug, in order to replace the CSS changes with the output from firediff.

Can I identify the location, (and ideally filename), of hte HTML document in the same sort of way from firebug?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read the template tutorials before removing anything from the template index.php. In general, you want the template to have provisions for every possibility that you might want. A well designed template will have the ability to display multiple columns in multiple positions as well as other positions to place banners, login boxes, weather widgets, or anything else you can think of. Then you simply code the template so that any position that is not being used does not get added to the final code of the page being displayed.

Official documentation - http://docs.joomla.org/Joomla!_1.5_Template_Tutorial

Once you have a good handle on how the template is supposed to work, the file you will be editing is in JOOMLA/templates/YOUR TEMPLATE/index.php

Be sure you get the whole module positions and collapsible module position thing before stripping anything out. A well thought out template will very rarely need any code editing, virtually everything should be done in the admin and with CSS page class and module class suffixes.

Comment: Thank you very much sir.  I shall be busy reading up before I do anymore.